# Does false life help vs. Power Word Kill?

Tags: spells, combat

We are playing D&D (high level wizard battles). We are going to fight a lich. Do you think False life would add to my maximum Hit Points and help vs Power Word Kill or no since the temporary hit points rule says "they aren't actual hit points but rather a buffer against damage." And we know Power Word Kill doesn't actually deal damage. So?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take a look at the [tour] and at the [help] if you need any guidance on the site! What D&D edition are you playing?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add a tag for the version of D&D you use.

Comment: Are you talking about 5e? Try this question mate https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/120274/73918

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do temporary hit points count as part of the HP for resisting certain magical effects?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/120274/do-temporary-hit-points-count-as-part-of-the-hp-for-resisting-certain-magical-ef)